# Weblogic managed servers internal communication with each other in a cluster

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic11g

I've created multiple managed servers in Weblogic. Each managed server has same IP(IP of weblogic server) and unique port.

I've installed ear and war files in these managed servers and all of them has their own context-root. 
For example I have ear file A with context-root A on server A and a war file B with context-root B on server B.
Whenever I browse IP:PORT(A) which has set on server A, this application needs some files on war file B which has deployed in server B. So A can not find its resources and I get error.
I should mention that I put them in a cluster too but nothing changed.

How can handle this matter?

Answer (score 0):

The cluster won't help you in this way because each web app is isolated from others in its own web container. If you need to share data or resources between web apps you can use a shared file system or a database for instance.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose I've used Oracle Http Server (OHS) plugin. after hours of searching in internet I've found that Weblogic application server does not implement anything to handle this issue.
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/webtier/